How to write file to tape using tar + pv to get progress bar
I have a tape drive DAT72 on /dev/nst0. When I do
tar -cvf /dev/nst0 myfile

there is no problem, it will write to the tape. Then I can do
tar -tvf /dev/nst0

and I can see the file on the tape.
But when I do
tar -cvpf - file1.ddd | (pv -T -r -p -e -t -b -s $(ls -l file1.ddd | awk '{print $5}') > /dev/nst0)

or
tar cvf - plik3.ddd | pv > /dev/nst0

the write process is OK (no errors from tar or the tape drive) but upon tar -tvf /dev/nst0 there is only:
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Generally I want to to use pv to get the progress bar, time, bitrate while writing to tape. What is the problem? How to make tar+pv work with the tape drive?
Of course before I read I rewind the tape because nst0 is non-rewinding.
This works fine:
tar -cvf - plik3.ddd | pv -T -t -r -e -b -p -s$(du -bs plik3.ddd | awk '{print $1}') | dd of=/dev/nst0 bs=256k
mt -f /dev/nst0 rewind
dd if=/dev/nst0 bs=256k | pv -T -t -r -b | tar -tvf -

